# Jquery Ajax Request cant read Done of undefind

Tags: jquery, ajax

Please help me why .done is not showing in intelligence and also its throughing an Error as `Cannot read property 'done' of undefined`

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#BtnSubmit').click(function () {
        var PromiseApi = CallingApi();
        PromiseApi.done(function (data) {
            alert(data.EmpName);
        })
    })

    function CallingApi() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/GetEmployee',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            type:'GET',
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: CallingApi doesn't seem to be returning anything..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function doesn't return anything, so its return value is `undefined`:

```
function CallingApi() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/GetEmployee',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        type:'GET',
    })
}
```

Add a return statement to return the promise object:

```
function CallingApi() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/GetEmployee',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        type:'GET',
    })
}
```